# Flag users/account who keep vulgar images as profile picture

Tags: feature-request

Is their any option to raised flag against account/user who are using bad/ culture less images as profile picture? i think introducing this flag be a good thing.

Comment: these down vote means that it is not a problem to keep naked pictures as profile pictures,isn't it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/3812734/bad-alloc

Comment: No, it's definitely not a problem that is so widespread that we would need to introduce a special flag type for it. Also, "bad" or "vulgar" are subjective, and I don't even know what you mean with "culture less". Oh, and the user you linked? That is a totally acceptable picture of a fully clothed female, it's definitely not "vulgar".

Comment: Here content is important, user profiles are not important. Also, it's quite likely that it isn't the user's own picture. For all you know, the user may be male, and has some reason for choosing that picture. It's a multi-cultural environment on SO, so don't take offence to profile pictures or anyone's "About Me" text.

Comment: Assuming the picture has not changed between when you posted the example link and when I saw it, I would like to know what you find offensive about it.

Comment: @PascalCuoq, it was a female of the human race showing parts of her mammary glands on a tight t-shirt.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you really think that a user has a profile image that is not within the terms of the site, then just go to one of their questions/answers/comments and click on **flag**. Select **other** and write why you are flagging. *Ex: "this users profile image is not suitable for the site".*

However, be forewarned that most moderators will likely decline your flag if the image your flagging about is not that bad.

Comment: It may depends on the culture of the country, is it?

Comment: Which country? SO has a multinational user base.